# How to compute variables for each subject in a dataset

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

I have reaction time and accuracy data that needs to be scored for each subject and I want to know which R package or functions would best meet my needs. Below is a snippet of what the data looks like for 2 subjects. Each row represents a single trial where the subject responds to a stimulus.

```
 date subject trialn blockcode     trialtype latency response correct
32913      15      1  practice    taskswitch    1765      205       1
32913      15      2  practice     cueswitch    4372      203       1
32913      15      3  practice cuerepetition    2523      203       0
32913      15      1      test     cueswitch    2239      205       1
32913      15      2      test cuerepetition    1244      203       1
32913      15      3      test    taskswitch    1472      203       0
32913      15      4      test     cueswitch    1877      205       1
32913      15      5      test    taskswitch    2271      203       1
30413      16      1  practice    taskswitch    1377      203       1
30413      16      2  practice    taskswitch    1648      203       1
30413      16      3  practice     cueswitch    1181      205       1
30413      16      1      test     cueswitch    1045      205       1
30413      16      2      test cuerepetition     969      203       0
30413      16      3      test     cueswitch     857      203       1
30413      16      4      test    taskswitch    1038      205       1
30413      16      5      test cuerepetition     836      203       0
```

Here's a description of what I'd like to do:

- Looking only at "test" trials, for each subject, calculate

  - the total number of trials
  - number of trials with latencies (i.e. reaction times) below 300ms
  - mean latency
  - mean correct
- Then, looking only at trials with latencies within 3 standard deviations of the subject's mean latency, calculate the mean latency for each trialtype
- Lastly, create a new data frame with all these variables and the subject ID and date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stackoverflow isn't really meant for tutorials, so make sure to check out the great online resources about `data.table`. 
The [website](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) is a good start and there are many questions about the package here
on SO that cover almost anything.

Here, I only want to show you how easy it can be if you are used to the syntax of the package.

First, let's load the package and read in your data:

```
library(data.table)
str <- "date subject trialn blockcode     trialtype latency response correct
        32913      15      1  practice    taskswitch    1765      205       1
        32913      15      2  practice     cueswitch    4372      203       1
        32913      15      3  practice cuerepetition    2523      203       0
        32913      15      1      test     cueswitch    2239      205       1
        32913      15      2      test cuerepetition    1244      203       1
        32913      15      3      test    taskswitch    1472      203       0
        32913      15      4      test     cueswitch    1877      205       1
        32913      15      5      test    taskswitch    2271      203       1
        30413      16      1  practice    taskswitch    1377      203       1
        30413      16      2  practice    taskswitch    1648      203       1
        30413      16      3  practice     cueswitch    1181      205       1
        30413      16      1      test     cueswitch    1045      205       1
        30413      16      2      test cuerepetition     969      203       0
        30413      16      3      test     cueswitch     857      203       1
        30413      16      4      test    taskswitch    1038      205       1
        30413      16      5      test cuerepetition     836      203       0"
DT <- as.data.table(read.table(text=str, header=TRUE))
```

Now, this is one thing that you asked for:

> Looking only at "test" trials, for each unique subject calculate the
>   total number of trials,  number of trials with latencies (i.e.
>   reaction times) below 300ms, mean latency mean correct (i.e.
>   accuracy).

```
DT[blockcode=="test", 
   list(TotalNr = .N,
        NrTrailLat = sum(latency < 300),
        MeanLat = mean(latency),
        MeanCor = mean(correct)), 
   by="subject"]
subject TotalNr NrTrailLat MeanLat MeanCor
1:      15       5          0  1820.6     0.8
2:      16       5          0   949.0     0.6
```

Basically, with those few lines of code I could answer all those questions. And in my opinion, the syntax is pretty straightforward as well.
For our `DT`, we only want to look at observations where `blockcode=="test"`. Next, we want to run all analysis for each subject separately.
That's easily done with the `by="subject"` statement. The cool thing: if you want to split by several dimensions, just add them...Instead
of ignoring practice, let's look at them separately:

```
DT[, 
   list(TotalNr = .N,
        NrTrailLat = sum(latency < 300),
        MeanLat = mean(latency),
        MeanCor = mean(correct)), 
   by="subject,blockcode"]
   subject blockcode TotalNr NrTrailLat  MeanLat   MeanCor
1:      15  practice       3          0 2886.667 0.6666667
2:      15      test       5          0 1820.600 0.8000000
3:      16  practice       3          0 1402.000 1.0000000
4:      16      test       5          0  949.000 0.6000000
```

Now don't tell me this isn't awesome!

Let's try another one:

> Also, create variables containing the last (or first) value of the
>   date and subjectID (this is in order to place data and subjectID in a
>   new dataframe).

I'm not sure what you mean here exactly because `date` does not change in your example for each subject. So let's make it a little bit harder. Let's say
we want to know the latency for each `subject,blockcode` combination for the first trial. To do so, we should first sort `DT` so that we know that
the first `trialn` is always 1. (This is not really necessary with this examplatory data because it seems sorted already).

```
setkey(DT, subject, blockcode, trialn)
DT[, list(FirstLat = latency[1]) , by="subject,blockcode"]
subject blockcode FirstLat
1:      15  practice     1765
2:      15      test     2239
3:      16  practice     1377
4:      16      test     1045
```

However, you wanted to add this as a new column in `DT`. To do so, you can use the `:=` operator:

```
DT[, FirstLat := latency[1] , by="subject,blockcode"]  
DT
date subject trialn blockcode     trialtype latency response correct FirstLat
1: 32913      15      1  practice    taskswitch    1765      205       1     1765
2: 32913      15      2  practice     cueswitch    4372      203       1     1765
3: 32913      15      3  practice cuerepetition    2523      203       0     1765
4: 32913      15      1      test     cueswitch    2239      205       1     2239
5: 32913      15      2      test cuerepetition    1244      203       1     2239
6: 32913      15      3      test    taskswitch    1472      203       0     2239
7: 32913      15      4      test     cueswitch    1877      205       1     2239
8: 32913      15      5      test    taskswitch    2271      203       1     2239
9: 30413      16      1  practice    taskswitch    1377      203       1     1377
10: 30413      16      2  practice    taskswitch    1648      203       1     1377
11: 30413      16      3  practice     cueswitch    1181      205       1     1377
12: 30413      16      1      test     cueswitch    1045      205       1     1045
13: 30413      16      2      test cuerepetition     969      203       0     1045
14: 30413      16      3      test     cueswitch     857      203       1     1045
15: 30413      16      4      test    taskswitch    1038      205       1     1045
16: 30413      16      5      test cuerepetition     836      203       0     1045
```

So those are just some thoughts to get you started. I took this effort because I wanted to show you that most things become quite easy when you understand
the basics. This should be motivation to make it through the manuals which can be a little bit overkill at the beginning. But it's worth the effort,
believe me! Because I haven't even mentioned the best part: `data.table` is also very fast. So good luck with your analysis.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick tutorial. I think both data.table and plyr are great options and I'm tempted to try both. I'll get started reading :)

Answer (score 3):

The plyr package is convenient for this sort of thing (also data.table, but I don't know its syntax). Here's an example to get started:

```
my_function <- function(tmp){
  data.frame(n_trials = sum(tmp[ ,'trialn']),
             n_trialslat  = sum(tmp[tmp[,'latency'] <= 300 ,'trialn']),
             mean_latency = mean(tmp[,'latency']))
}
library(plyr)
ddply(subset(d, blockcode == "test"), 'subject', my_function)
```

Comment: I added some thoughts about `data.table`.

Comment: Thanks for the demonstration and for suggesting plyr and data.table. It was a tough choice accepting the best answer as they are both very helpful.